# Use 1 Columns Values as a search array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which searches for individual values across a whole workbook. the problem I have is that I need to type in all the codes I am searching for individually but the code selection is already contained in a single column on a worksheet within the workbook. Basically what I want the search to do is to look at the values in this column and use them as the array across the whole workbook.

My total code looks like this

```
Sub FMES()

Dim Headers() As String: Headers = Split("FMES CODE,Part No,Part Name,FM ID,Failure Mode & Cause,FMCN,PTR,ETR", ",")

    Worksheets.Add().Name = "FMES"
    Dim wsFMES As Worksheet: Set wsFMES = Sheets("FMES")
    wsFMES.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    wsFMES.Cells.Clear

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsFMES
        For i = 0 To UBound(Headers)
            .Cells(2, i + 2) = Headers(i)
            .Columns(i + 2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Next i
        .Cells(1, 2) = "FMES TABLE"
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, UBound(Headers) + 2)).MergeCells = True
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, UBound(Headers) + 2)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(2, UBound(Headers) + 2)).Font.Bold = True
    End With

    Dim SourceCell As Range, FirstAdr As String
    Dim RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 3

    Dim SearchTarget() As String
    SearchTarget = Split("TM-CRIT-PART,TM-U-IFSD-HPT,TM-D-IFSD-HPT,TM-HPT-CBO,TM-HPT2-NGV-BURN-MIN,TM-HPT2-NGV-MAJ,TM-HPT-INTGRTY-LOSS,OIL-FZ2-MINOR LEAK,OIL-FZ2-MAJOR LEAK,FIRE-OIL-ZN2", ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(SearchTarget)
        If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
            With Sheets(j)
                Set SourceCell = .Columns(8).Find(SearchTarget(i), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAdr = SourceCell.Address
                    Do
                        wsFMES.Cells(RowCounter, 2).Value = SearchTarget(i)
                        wsFMES.Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value = .Cells(3, 10)
                        wsFMES.Cells(RowCounter, 4).Value = .Cells(2, 10)
                        wsFMES.Cells(RowCounter, 5).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 2).Value
                        For k = 0 To SourceCell.Row - 1
                            If .Cells(SourceCell.Row - k, 3).Value <> "continued." Then
                                wsFMES.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row - k, 3).Value
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next k
                        wsFMES.Cells(RowCounter, 7).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 14).Value


                        Set SourceCell = .Columns(8).FindNext(SourceCell)
                        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
                    Loop While Not SourceCell Is Nothing And SourceCell.Address <> FirstAdr
                End If
            End With
            Next j
        End If
    Next i


    End Sub
```

The section that defines my search criteria is

```
  Dim SearchTarget() As String
    SearchTarget = Split("TM-CRIT-PART,TM-U-IFSD-HPT,TM-D-IFSD-HPT,TM-HPT-CBO,TM-HPT2-NGV-BURN-MIN,TM-HPT2-NGV-MAJ,TM-HPT-INTGRTY-LOSS,OIL-FZ2-MINOR LEAK,OIL-FZ2-MAJOR LEAK,FIRE-OIL-ZN2", ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(SearchTarget)
        If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
            With Sheets(j)
                Set SourceCell = .Columns(8).Find(SearchTarget(i),
```

The codes it is searching for are the TM-CRIT-PART...etc my problem is that there are hundreds of these and they are all contained in a worksheet called FMES Codes between Cells A4 and A397. Is there a way I can define the values in this range of cells as my search criteria ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simple solution when passing range to variable which is not a `Object variable` you will get a two-dimensional array. There are some changes required in your code. Follow the code:

```
Dim SearchTarget As Variant         '<<change type, remove brackets
    SearchTarget = Sheets("FMES").Range("A4:A297")  '<<define array 
           'our array is now two dimensional starting with (1,1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(SearchTarget, 1)    '<<change starting point and loop scope
        '...some of your code here
        Set SourceCell = .Columns(8).Find(SearchTarget(i, 1),   '<<changes here
```

**Hint!** It is possible to convert two-dimensional array coming from single `Colum Range` into one-dimensional array. if required use `Transpose function`.

Comment: I have changed my code to this `im SearchTarget As Variant
    SearchTarget = Sheets("FMES Codes").Range("A4:A397")

    For i = 0 To UBound(SearchTarget, 1)
        If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
            With Sheets(j)
                Set SourceCell = .Columns(8).Find(SearchTarget(I, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)`          However it is throwing out an error saying the script is out of range for this line `Set SourceCell = .Columns(8).Find(SearchTarget(I, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)`

Comment: i don't know if there is maybe a problem with the SourceCell phrasing as it has already been defined as a range